# Why not using <<EOF instead of cat <<EOF?

Tags: zsh, cat, io-redirection

I'm wondering when using `cat <<` is preferable over simply using `<<`. I'm testing in a ZSH shell and

```
cat <<EOF
Hello world!
EOF
```

outputs the same of

```
<<EOF
Hello world!
EOF
```

.

```
var=$(cat <<EOF
Hello world!
EOF
)
```

has the same variable value of

```
var=$(<<EOF
Hello world!
EOF
)
```

What are the practical differences between the two forms of here-doc?

Comment: You might tag this `zsh` instead of `shell`, since it's only applicable to that single shell.

Comment: Yes, it's better. I didn't know it was a zsh very specific extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as zsh default behavior (for example invoking `zsh -f`), there is no defference between the two examples. We could check the trace output with invoking the two examples with `zsh -x -f`, `cat` will be called actually even in the latter case.

Although these differences are described in [Redirections with no command, `zshmisc(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirections-with-no-command). zsh will behave in several ways for redirections with no command, so we can do about it to not break anything:

- To use `cat` explicitly.
- To set the localoptions/parameters.

> Redirections with no command
>
> When a simple command consists of one or more redirection operators and zero or more parameter assignments, but no command name, zsh can behave in several ways.
>
> If the parameter [NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-NULLCMD) is not set or the option [CSH_NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CSH_005fNULLCMD) is set, an error is caused. This is the csh behavior and [CSH_NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CSH_005fNULLCMD) is set by default when emulating csh.
>
> If the option [SH_NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SH_005fNULLCMD) is set, the builtin ‘:’ is inserted as a command with the given redirections. This is the default when emulating sh or ksh.
>
> Otherwise, if the parameter [NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-NULLCMD) is set, its value will be used as a command with the given redirections. If both [NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-NULLCMD) and [READNULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-READNULLCMD) are set, then the value of the latter will be used instead of that of the former when the redirection is an input. The default for [NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-NULLCMD) is ‘cat’ and for [READNULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-READNULLCMD) is ‘more’.Thus
>
> < file
>
> shows the contents of file on standard output, with paging if that is a terminal. [NULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-NULLCMD) and [READNULLCMD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-READNULLCMD) may refer to shell functions.
>
> -- [Redirections with no command, `zshmisc(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirections-with-no-command)

So, in the latter case, `$var` will not be set if the zsh shell option `SH_NULLCMD` is set, etc.

```sh
# I've tested with running `zsh -f` to check the various behaviors.
test-nullcmd () {
  local var=$(<<EOF
Hello world!
EOF
)
  echo "$var"
}

test-nullcmd
#> Hello world!

() {
  setopt localoptions shnullcmd
  test-nullcmd
}
# nothing will be printed

() {
  setopt localoptions cshnullcmd
  test-nullcmd
}
# test-nullcmd:1: redirection with no command (error)

() {
  local NULLCMD=
  test-nullcmd
}
# test-nullcmd:1: redirection with no command (error)
```

BTW, we could use `command cat` rather than `cat` solely to prevent alias expansions.

Comment: Awesome answer. Documented, tested and with a good advice about the unalias of cat. Thank you very much!

Comment: how about bash?  "<<EOF" ouputs nothing

Answer (score 1):

The behavior described is zsh-only. On zsh, this is a significant performance enhancement over unnecessarily invoking an external binary (`/bin/cat`).

If you wanted to emit a heredoc's contents to stdout without overhead of starting an external tool such as `cat` on a POSIX shell such as bash, you'd need something like the following instead:

```
# read heredoc into $var, terminated by first NUL, w/ truthy exit status
IFS= read -r -d '' var <<'EOF' ||:
content goes here
EOF

# emit $var to stdout
printf '%s' "$var"
```

The zsh syntax, while not guaranteed by POSIX, is significantly more terse than the `read; printf` approach, while being significantly faster than `cat`.